# How to assign values from a dynamically created input field to individual variables in Python

Tags: python

I want to assign the values from a dynamically created input field in HTML to individual variables in python.

My HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number>
```

I got the values in as list python by using bellow code

```
mynum = request.POST.getlist('addmore[]')
```

How I can assign the values from mynum to individual varibles ?

I tried below:

```
val1 = mynum[0]
val2 = mynum[1]
val3 = mynum[2]
val4 = mynum[3]
```

But if the I enter 2 values , then I get error saying 'index out of range'

How can I get the values  in val2, val2, val3...as per the number of list entries ?

Comment: This doesn't look like pure Python; what libraries/modules are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary whose key is the variable and value is actual value of the variable:

```
d = {f'var{i+1}': x for i, x in enumerate(mynum)}
```

Now, you can call each similar way you use normal variables. For ex: `d['var1']` gives value of `num[0]`.